# how to update a special sub rows in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

i know how to update a database rows using pdo.

For instance to update the row **meta_key** where **userid** is **15**. I can just do

```
$meta_data='mycontent';
$user_id b='15';
$update1 = $db->prepare('
            UPDATE my_table set
            meta_key = :meta_key WHERE user_id= :user_id');

        $update1->execute(array(
            ':meta_key' => $meta_data,':user_id' => $user_id));
```

Here is the update is a bit complex as can be seen in the screenshot below.

[image: screenshot]

**user_id** is 15 for both **meta_key** and **meta_value** columns

**meta_key** column has three rows **first_name,last_name,description** while for **meta_value** columns, the corresponding row values are empty.

I need to update the rows values of  **meta_values** to equate **meta_key** rows where **user_id is 15**

For instance. this is what i want via updates statements in my database

```
**user_id  meta_key      meta_value**

  15     first_name    john

  15     last_name     canoon

  15     description    I am john cannon
```

Therotically, I need to initiate variables like this  as usual

```
$first_name='john';
$last_name='canoon'; 
$desc='I am john cannon';
$user_id b='15';

$meta['first_name']=$first_name;
$meta['last_name']=$last_name;
$meta['description']=$desc;
```

please how will the updates looks like. 
I guessed I have to use for each loop something  like code below.
 can someone help me out

```
foreach ( $meta as $key => $value ) {
    // updates database
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $first_name='john';
    $last_name='canoon'; 
    $desc='I am john cannon';
    $user_id ='15';

    $meta['first_name']=$first_name;
    $meta['last_name']=$last_name;
    $meta['description']=$desc;
```

**Solution -1**
Use the prepared statement. prepared statement is a feature used to execute the same (or similar) SQL statements repeatedly.

```
<?php

$sql = "UPDATE my_table SET meta_values=:meta_values WHERE meta_key =:meta_key and user_id = $user_id ";
$query = $db->prepare($sql);

foreach($meta as $key => $value){
   $query->bindParam(':meta_values', $value);
   $query->bindParam(':meta_key', $key);
   $query->execute();
}
```

**Solution 2**

On based on table structure I see that you are using WordPress. And trying to update the wp_usermeta table. To update the wp_usermeta you can use update_user_meta.

```
<?php
foreach($meta as $key => $value) {
    update_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $value );
}
?>
```